# HTML "class" and "id" attributes using hyphens instead of undescores in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, naming-conventions, conventions

Rails fills the `id` and `class` of an element generated with various `input` tag helpers (`text_field` for example) by itself. For example, in a `form_for(@athlete)`, adding a `text_field :height` generates

```
<input name="athlete_height" ... />
```

I am a strong advocate of the use of hyphens in HTML ids and classes (and in CSS selectors consequently) (by reading [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Underscores_in_class_and_ID_Names), because I like to write using the conventions dictated by the language - like in `data-stuff` - and because it's just better looking).

I read here and there that in Rails you can't fix this. This would be quite disappointing.
Do you know a way around this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid, underscores are hardcoded. From https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb, lines 446-450:

```
options[:html].reverse_merge!(
  class:  as ? "#{action}_#{as}" : dom_class(object, action),
  id:     (as ? [namespace, action, as] : [namespace, dom_id(object, action)]).compact.join("_").presence,
          method: method
)
```

you can always provide your own id and class, or patch code of ActionView, which may be hard, tedious and error-prone

Comment: You could also override `dom_class` and `dom_id` to do something like `super.dasherize`

Answer (score 0):

Recently ran into this very same situation and @lobanovadik has a good solution: just write your own helper method.

```
# app/helpers/dom_helper.rb
module DomHelper
  dom_id_helper(model)
    dom_id(model).dasherize
  end
end

# view.html.erb
<%= link_to "Text", path, id: dom_id_helper(@model) %>
  #=> <a href="path", id: "model-ID">Text</a>
```

This has the benefit of not monkey-patching Rails or messing with any default methods/configuration.  Thus, you won't "break" any updates to Rails.

It also gives you greater flexibility because you can now use both dashes or underscores depending on the situation. For instance, let's say there's a gem that expects IDs to have underscores...you won't break it.

As a personal preference, I always append `_helper` to all my own helper methods, so that I know it's a helper method and that it came from me and not from Rails (easier to debug).